# mail.ru imap поиск письма

Tags: python

Не работает поиск письма через FROM,SUBLECT, выдает ошибку [b'[CANNOT] Unsupported search criterion: 
Фильтровать не хочу,т.к на почте 10к+ писем

```
import imaplib
server = "imap.mail.ru"
login = "123123"
password = "123123"


box = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)

box.login(login, password)

box.select('INBOX')

data = box.search(None, '(From "Отправитель")')
print(data)
 вот
```

Comment: Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос. Например, кодом, иллюстрирующим проблему

Comment: В шапке изменил

Comment: Не знаю что там про мейл.ру, но в спеке (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4) скобок нет. И FROM все буквы заглавные. Как альтернатива можно попробовать HEADER FROM. И если искать что-то юникодное, то не помешает указать CHARSET

Comment: Пытался и так сделать,не помогло

Comment: Всё просто. mail.ru не поддерживает поиск. Заводите ящик в другом месте.